# Redefinition of \today -- Clash with babel

Tags: babel

I want my calendar dates to be formatted like DD.MM.YYYY

As I am from germany I use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. `babel` breaks my redefinition of `\today` to use leading zeros and I don´t know why it is not possible for me to redefine it. If `babel` is commented out, it works fine. But defining a new command which produces the desired format is possible, see the MWE below. Can someone explain why it is not possible to redefine `\today`? And is it safe to redefine it or might I break some things up that rely on `\today` so that it would be wiser to `\todayx`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\newcommand{\leadingzero}[1]{\ifnum #1<10 0\the#1\else\the#1\fi}
\renewcommand{\today}{\leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year}
\newcommand{\todayx}{\leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year}
\begin{document}
\today \\
\todayx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but how would you like the date to be formatted? As `\todayx`?

Comment: Yes exactly, `\todayx` gives me what I want but it would be nicer to use `\today` (in my opinion).

Comment: Use `datetime` or `datetime2` package and your formatting issues will be solved, I think

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I was posting an answer with `datetime`, but is `datetime2` supposed to be the new version?

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, but I never used it so far... I don't know the real differences there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel` does definitions right at the start of `\begin{document}`, so even if `\today` is redefined **after** `\usepackage{babel}` this is not sufficient, but placing it in the `\AtBeginDocument` - hook will work. This does not require extra packages (although there nice packages such as `datetime` or `datetime2`!)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newcommand{\leadingzero}[1]{\ifnum #1<10 0\the#1\else\the#1\fi}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\today}{\leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year}
\newcommand{\todayx}{\leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year}
}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0em
\today 

\todayx
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. So I guess it doesn't matter where you place the redefinition as long as `babel` is loaded?

Comment: @Alenanno: No, I don't think so, since `babel`'s `\AtBeginDocument` stuff is placed later then, overwritting the O.P. versions of `\today` ...

Comment: Christian is right, simply moving my commands behind `\begin{document}` also solves the issue (but is not a good solution indeed ;-) )

Comment: @Enno: That is possible too, of course, but for more general features, `\AtBeginDocument` (say in `package` or `class` code), is the better approach

Comment: @Christian: I definitely agree with you on that point.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the `datetime` package with the `ddmmyyyy` option and `\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}` for the separator.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\newcommand{\leadingzero}[1]{\ifnum #1<10 0\the#1\else\the#1\fi}
%\renewcommand{\today}{\leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year}
\newcommand{\todayx}{\leadingzero{\day}.\leadingzero{\month}.\the\year}

\begin{document}
Today: \today

Todayx: \todayx
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here's the `datetime2` solution, but note that although it's using one of the base numeric styles it also requires [`datetime2-german`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-german) (which is implicitly loaded) to prevent interference from `babel`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ddmmyyyy,datesep=.]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: 24.08.2016]