# Redefine the abbreviated months with datetime2 package

Tags: date, datetime2

I was wondering if there is a way to redefine the abbreviated months with [`datetime2`](https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf) package, such that, when using the command `\today`, months are written exactly like the first column of the image below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{abbr}
\begin{document}
    \today
\end{document}
```

There is already a solution---[How to make a lowercase month name with \today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145688/how-to-make-a-lowercase-month-name-with-today)---with `datetime` package to redefine the month style, but this package creates a confit with my document.

Thanks.

[image]

**EDIT** in light of @quark67's solution:

I identified the conflict using quark67's solution to be with `\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}`, used for hyphenation. I just had to remove the argument `[USenglish]` to make quark67's solution works, but I would still like to keep `\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}`.

**SOLUTION**

In reference to this post: [Redefinition of \today -- Clash with babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326177/redefinition-of-today-clash-with-babel), placing @quark67's code inside `\AtBeginDocument{...}` solved it.

Comment: Please add exactly the document class you need (ruthesis according to a comment) and all package you need to use. My answer needs adjustement for May, June and July. But what is false with the other months?

Comment: I have updated my code. But I cannot guess what are the additional packages (which you mentioned in a comment) you uses, so perharps this code don't work for you.

Comment: Thank you @quark67 for your help. This is the right solution that I was looking for. I have identified the conflict in `\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}` that I use for hyphenation. I just needed to remove the argument `[USenglish]`. I'm not sure how this will impact my document. Would you be able to work around this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (note the loading of the package **datetime2-calc** for the conversion from numeric value to the short month name).

**Edit:** As you say you need the document class **ruthesis** (https://scholarship.rice.edu/handle/1911/21747) in a comment, I update my code with this document class.

Also, as you have added a new requirement (June must be abbreviated as "June", no "Jun.", and July as "July", no "Jul."), I have updated the code (and corrected my dummy bug, May is never abbreviated as "May.")

**Edit 2:** "September" is abbreviated "Sept.", not "Sep.", as in the first column of the table.

```latex
\documentclass{ruthesis}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\usepackage{datetime2-calc}

\DTMnewdatestyle{mydate}{%
   \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
   \edef\paramTwo{##2}%
   \def\monthV{05}%
   \def\monthVI{06}%
   \def\monthVII{07}%
   \def\monthIX{09}%
     \DTMshortmonthname{##2}%
     \ifx\paramTwo\monthV%
     \else\ifx\paramTwo\monthVI%
     e%
     \else\ifx\paramTwo\monthVII
     y%
     \else\ifx\paramTwo\monthIX
     t.%
     \else
     .%
     \fi\fi\fi\fi% 
     \ \DTMtwodigits{##3}, ##1}%
   \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
 }

\DTMsetdatestyle{mydate}

\begin{document}
    \today % Mar. 11, 2023
    
    \DTMdate{2023-06-11}
    
    \DTMdate{2023-05-11}
    
    \DTMdate{2023-04-11}
    
    \DTMdate{2023-07-11}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

In a comment, you say that the previous code don't work because of a package you uses, but you don't say which additional packages you uses, so I cannot guarantee this code will work in your real usage.

Comment: Thank you @quark67 for this solution, but for some reason, it is not working with my thesis document. It outputs:
"March 10, 2023."

I need to comply with IEEE standards. I think there is a conflict with this definition that I have:

`
\def\@month{\ifcase\month ?\or \textsc{January}\or \textsc{February}\or \textsc{March}\or \textsc{April}\or \textsc{May}\or \textsc{June}\or \textsc{July}\or \textsc{August}\or \textsc{September}\or \textsc{October}\or \textsc{November}\or \textsc{December}\fi}
`

Comment: Welcome. Can you please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? In your code, you uses the **article** document class. What is the real document class you uses? From where comes the definition `\@month`? Is it so in your preamble? Add also your required packages. Thanks.

Comment: The document class that I'm using is `report.` It's different from my example, sorry. The definition of`\@month?` is in a `.cls` document. Do you know a quick way to copy a long code here, so you can check this document?
Thanks.

Comment: Here is the document class:
newtextdocument.com/t/f9e9d1cfab

Comment: @AEW I have downloaded `ruthesis.cls` from https://scholarship.rice.edu/handle/1911/21747 (seems to be the same version as yours), installed in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/ruthesis` (on my Mac), then replaced `\documentclass{article}` by `\documentclass{ruthesis}` and all works as expected.

Comment: Yes, that's the right document @quark67. I re-downloaded it again, and copied to my source files folder, but still not working. Probably, there Is a conflict with one of the packages that I'm using in the main tex file.

Comment: Do you know if there is a solution similar to this:
[link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145688/how-to-make-a-lowercase-month-name-with-today?rq=1).
I would like to even change the months abbreviations as in here:
[link](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch10/psec039.html).

Comment: @AEW That's why we always needs [Minimal Working  Example]{https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228}. But not too minimal ;). Here try to find the package which make the conflict in your use case, perhaps I can help you.

Comment: @AEW you link to the Chicago Manual of Style needs a login.

Comment: Yes @quark67, sorry. I have added a screenshot of it to the question. I need to have months written exactly like the first column of the table.